# Netbeans "Remote Terminal Tab" alt / ctrl and other key combinations doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, netbeans, ssh, terminal

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2.

Recently, I had discovered the "Remote Terminal Tab" option and it is cool. It can be very useful under certain circumstances. It is located under "Window menu"->"IDE Tools"->"Terminal".

It seems to work properly, exactly like putty / or other ssh client. BUT there is a problem with key combinations interpretation.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>< any ></kbd> doesn't work, seems like the <kbd>Tab</kbd> ignores the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key completely. So, if you used to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd>/<kbd>left arrow</kbd> this functionality is not available.

The same for control. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd>/<kbd>left arrow</kbd> and many others results unexpected behavior. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>r</kbd>,<kbd>s</kbd>,<kbd>c</kbd>,<kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>some others</kbd> work, but certain combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd>/<kbd>left arrow</kbd>, <kbd>backspace</kbd>, and <kbd>many others</kbd> doesn't work.

Simple steps to reproduce and understand the problem:

- open "Remote Terminal Tab" (setup connection... connect to you remote host)
- run the [read](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read) command

> centos_artur:~$ read

now type combinations with <kbd>alt</kbd> key, for example <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>/<kbd>left</kbd>, you'll get:

> d^[[D^[[C

now, for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>,<kbd>right</kbd>, you'll get:

> ^[[D^[[C

Now open any native linux bash terminal, for example centos. Run the same read command, and this what you'll get as output:

```
Alt  + d     = ^[d
Alt  + left  = ^[[1;3D
Alt  + right = ^[[1;3C
Ctrl + left  = ^[[1;5D
Ctrl + right = ^[[1;5C
```

The question is: 
How to make those combinations work in NetBeans "Remote Terminal Tab" ? How to fix it? I read something about NetBeans use <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for internal use only short-cuts, I assume this related, but doesn't help solving the problem.

I tested with Netbeans on Windows 7 and Linux(on CentOS) versions. And got the same behaviour on both...

A bug opened for the issue on I found this bug description (https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236268) on netbeans bugzilla site.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common problem while working with consoles... Problem is, that there is a serialization going on between the host computer (keyboard driver etc) and the virtual terminal (serial VT). In my experience, not even an oldschool tool like Putty or even cygwin has 100% implementations.

You have to rely on netbeans dev team